# Nodejs Application how to get SSL certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, ssl

I got a websocket application on express&node.

It works well on "http" but I need to let it work on https.
(my provider is digitalocean)

```
'use strict';
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app)
var io = require("socket.io")(http, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  }
});
var users = []
....
```

So that,
I add blabla.mydomain.com and add it an SSL certificate on AWS Certificate Manager. (my domain is on AWS)

But it doesnt work.
When I type http://xx.xxx.xx:8080, it works well.
But If I type https://xx.xx.xx:8080, it returns error with "no secure connection"

What must I do?

How can I define my Certificate manager's SSL to my express.js project?

Comment: You can't use the Amazon Certificate Manager for this, it only works with certain resources in AWS: API-Gateway, Application Load Balancer, Network Load Balancer, CloudFront.

Comment: hmm, can we use certbot without any nginx or apache?